# how to get custom message headers of wcf service in android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf, custom-headers

I am using this  ->> **[link](http://trycatch.me/adding-custom-message-headers-to-a-wcf-service-using-inspectors-behaviors/)**  <<-  all code for setting custom message headers in wcf but i am unable to get these headers inform ation in android. if anyone have any experices in android. how to get these type of custom  message header values in android.

**Like this code in C#**

```
public class SimpleCustomHeaderService : ISimpleCustomHeaderService
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        //Do Work
        //...

        //Capture Headers
        var userName = GetHeader("web-user", "ns");
        var webNodeId = GetHeader("web-node-id", "ns");
        var webSessionId = GetHeader("web-session-id", "ns");

        Debug.WriteLine("User: {0} / Node: {1} / Session: {2}", userName, webNodeId, webSessionId);
        var s = string.Format("HeaderInfo: {0}, {1}, {2}",
            userName,
            webNodeId,
            webSessionId);

        return s;
    }

    private static T GetHeader(string name, string ns)
    {
        return OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader(name, ns) > -1
            ? OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader(name, ns)
            : default(T);
    }
}
```

But i am doing these setting header information in android like this, but unable to get. What is the change needed for getting header information.

**Method 1**

```
 private static final String    NAMESPACE   = "http://tempuri.org/";
 Element[] header = new Element[1];
 header[0]=buildAuthHeader();
 envelope.headerOut = header;
 Log.i("header", "" + envelope.headerOut.toString());

    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.bodyOut = request;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    int Timeout = 15 * 1000;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,1000*60*2);
    Log.i("bodyout", "" + envelope.bodyOut.toString());
    Log.i("REQUEST", "" + request.toString());

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        returnString = response.toString();
        Log.i("RESPONSE==", response.toString());
```

---

```
private Element buildAuthHeader() {
        String n_s = "ns";
            String web_user_test="john";
    int node_id=1234554;
    //String gid= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    //String xmlns_soap1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/";
    //String Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
    //String xmlns_soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/";
    Element h = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "ns");
    Element first = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "web-user");
    first.addChild(Node.TEXT,web_user_test);
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, first);

    Element second = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "web-node-id");
    second.addChild(Node.TEXT, String.valueOf(node_id));
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, second);

    Element third = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "web-session-id");
    third.addChild(Node.TEXT, String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, third);
        return h;
    }
```

***I have got Output:*** `RESPONSE== HeaderInfo: , 0, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

**Method 2**

I have also doing this alternative setting header:

```
            U= new User();
    U.setProperty(0, "horrorgoogle");
    U.setProperty(1,node_id);
    U.setProperty(2,UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

---

```
    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("web-user", U.getProperty(0).toString()));
    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("web-node-id", U.getProperty(1).toString()));
    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("web-session-id", U.getProperty(2).toString()));
```

---

```
   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headerList);
```

I have also get same error both method.

***I have got Output:*** `RESPONSE== HeaderInfo: , 0, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

Would you please, find out where is error on my code. I am very glad , if you really help me for this my big problem.

Thank you so much reading my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you had set your header correctly. I dont see where you set the header[0].
Maybe you have to insert this line of code

```
envelope.headerOut = header;
```

Comment: I faced: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Element to Element[].

Comment: Could you try this line of code envelope.headerOut = header;

Comment: Yeah, i try  `envelope.headerOut = header[0];` but get above error.  i forget to put in my code above. but i  already put  `envelope.headerOut = header;` in mycode.

Comment: no it is not work friend. still i have return `RESPONSE== HeaderInfo: , 0, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`